# USB COM port data reading error

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, windows

I am using people count device to read the InCount, Out Count record and it is connected with my PC COM3 USB port.. I have written the code to fetch the data, I am continuously receiving the below message while reading the data..... can I have some code or idea to fetch the record?

message is.... The operation has timed out.

**mycode is below:**

```
Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    ' Receive strings from a serial port. 
    Dim returnStr As String = ""

    Dim com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort
    'SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);     

    Try
        com1 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM3")
        com1.BaudRate = 115200
        com1.ReadTimeout = 10000

        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = com1.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If com1 IsNot Nothing Then com1.Close()
    End Try

    Return returnStr
End Function
```

Comment: Are you certain that the device is sending a newline?

Comment: I think so..but not sure..

Comment: Well, then try returnStr &= Char.ConvertFromUtf32(com1.ReadChar()) and see if you get any results.

Comment: This code is very unlikely to work correctly.  You can't ignore handshaking and the device is quite unlikely to constantly report "nobody here".  If you can't link to a manual for the device then contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

You must know at least the following 7 parameter settings for the device you are trying to communicate with and set your serial port properties to match.

PortName 
BaudRate 
Parity
DataBits 
StopBits
NewLine
Handshake

Some of these you might guess (Parity is usually none, Databits is usually 8 stop bits is usually 1, handshake is often none).  But Hans is correct unless you get all these set properly you will never communicate with your device.  Also it is better to open your serial port once during initialization of your program and then leave it open until the program closes.